# Stream processor didn't process messages correct first, then multiplicates it

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have two topics which are connected by a StreamProcessor:

TopicA -> ProcessorA -> TopicB

1. I send a message for the first to Topics a which gets recorded there and then through the ProcessorA processed and it ends up in TopicB.
2. The behaviour of #1 repeats but not really in a constant pattern

Any ideas what can be done to solve this issue?

Comment: Any logs, sample code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is solved.

The problem was a side effect by storing a local variable in the instance of a class which caused some weird things and quite unpredictable ( invariants ) !